# How get value from property file to input in springConfig.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

I want to get the property value in email.properties file to input in the springConfig.xml. but there is an error occur.

here is my code below

springConfig.xml

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"
    id="mailSender">
    <property name="host" value="${email.host}" />
    <property name="protocol" value="${email.protocol}" />
    <property name="port" value="${email.port}" />
    <property name="username" value="${email.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${email.password}" />
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
            <prop key="mail.smtp.ssl.trust">smtp.gmail.com</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

here is the property file

```
email.host=stmp.gmail.com
email.port=465
email.protocol=smtp
email.username=xxx@gmail.com
email.password=xxxxxxxx
```

here is the error trace

```
Jun 15, 2015 10:46:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [springConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:430)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
    ... 26 more

Jun 15, 2015 10:46:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class kh.com.gfam.rsos.listener.InitializeApplicationListner
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [springConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:700)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:479)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:505)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1502)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
    at org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.parseNumber(NumberUtils.java:155)
    at org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.CustomNumberEditor.setAsText(CustomNumberEditor.java:113)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertTextValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:430)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.doConvertValue(TypeConverterDelegate.java:403)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:459)
    ... 26 more

Jun 15, 2015 10:46:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [D:\Sample Project 2 (RSOS)\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rsos]
Jun 15, 2015 10:46:17 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [D:\Sample Project 2 (RSOS)\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rsos\WEB-INF\resources\log4j.xml]
log4j:ERROR Could not parse url [file:/D:/Sample%20Project%202%20(RSOS)/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/rsos/WEB-INF/resources/log4j.xml].
java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Sample Project 2 (RSOS)\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\rsos\WEB-INF\resources\log4j.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:131)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:87)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator$2.parse(DOMConfigurator.java:765)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:871)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.doConfigure(DOMConfigurator.java:778)
    at org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator.configure(DOMConfigurator.java:906)
    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4751)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5175)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: where is the logic/code that take the values from the properties file into the springConfig.xml ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this line of your stack trace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mailSender' defined in class path resource [springConfig.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'int' for property 'port'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${email.port}"
```

It says that your variable `port` have to be an `int` and you are trying to store it as a `String` so you will have to put it like this:

```
<property name="port">${email.port}</property>
```

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to try like this .Create a property file on classpath then give the reference to application-context.xml .

```
<!-- App Properties -->
<beans:bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="properties" ref="appProperties" />
</beans:bean>

<bean id="appProperties"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="singleton" value="true" />
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true" />
    <property name="locations">
        <!-- Note: Properties defined in later files will override properties 
            defined earlier files, in case of overlapping keys. Hence, make sure that 
            the most specific files are the last ones in the given list of locations. -->
        <list>
            <value>classpath:properties/email.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!-- App Properties End -->
```

Hopes above configuration helps you.:) Let me known any query.

Answer (score 2):

I think you haven't declared the [property placeholder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.html) in your spring configuration xml file.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">

        <property name="location">
            <value>email.properties</value> //location of email.properties file
        </property>
</bean>
```

If you are working on Spring 3.1 or above just provide

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:email.properties" />
```

The email.properties file should be placed under /src/main/resources so that it will be available on the classpath at runtime.

[This is a nice article on property configuration](http://www.baeldung.com/2012/02/06/properties-with-spring/).

Comment: I put the both springConfig.xml and  email.properties file in resouce folder so !! how could i write the location ?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to setup the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer as mentioned above. Your property file seems to be in the classpath (resource folder), so simply add "classpath:" - "classpath:email.properties".